# What does Ember-simple-auth check against?

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I have been looking for answer of implementing ember-simple-auth (oauth2-password-grant) for days without luck. I use firebase to sign up users, which is successful. However on the log in page, the action of `this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', credentials)` seems to cause a json error `(SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)`.

So my first question is, in theory, how does this authentication check if the user's email/password is correct? Meaning, in which file is the "answer" located? Am I supposed to define a token? If yes, I already tried "serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4200/' or serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4200/token" and nothing works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ember simple auth sends login request to API(in your case Firebase). If entered credentials are valid your API will authenticate user, create and save auth token. Authenticated user with created token will be sent to Ember and token will be saved in local storage by Ember simple auth. Every subsequent request from Ember after login needs to include that token in its header and API will authenticate your request based on that token(comparing token from Ember with the one saved in API).

Comment: thanks for answering. 1) In whole login / auth process, i didn't see any tutorial mentioning firebase, so which .js file takes the user input /password to firebase , and how token will be created (by whom) based on permission of firebase.  2) both firebase and oauth2 use application.js in adapter, one is  FirebaseAdapter the other is JSONAPIAdapter, how i can let these two coexist in one .js file? if not, what kind of folder i need create to handle them separately?

Comment: My answer was overview of what simple auth does. Sry but I'm not familiar how Ember works with Firebase and I don't have time to look into it. Maybe this addon can help you https://github.com/jamesdixon/ember-cli-simple-auth-firebase

Comment: your previous answer also lead me to use authenticator:firebase rather than authenticator:oauth2, although i believe these are 2 different methods.  Thanks still and i will post update once i have!

Comment: For anyone who happens to be in the same boat, i ended up using firebase signiniwthemailandpassword directly without using ember simple auth or torii, for now. And beforemodel is used to check login user (again, with firebase's auth directly)